# How can one transform an arbitrary 2D metric to coordinates in which it's conformally flat?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, conformal-field-theory

I know all two dimensional metrics (in my case Lorentzian) are conformally flat, but I can't seem to prove it. I have a particularly complicated metric, and it would make my life much easier if I could transform it into coordinates in which it is conformally flat. Does anyone know the way to do this in general?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Diffeomorphism & Weyl transformations in the 2D worldsheet of string theory and the existence of conformal gauge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410900/2451)