# Diffeomorphism invariance in 2 dimensional metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, string-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

I am reading "String Theory and M-Theory" by Becker, Becker and Schwarz. In Chapter 2, the authors try to gauge fix the auxiliary field. They start from the general expression
$$h_{\alpha\beta}=\begin{pmatrix}
  h_{00} & h_{01}\\ 
  h_{01} & h_{11}
\end{pmatrix}\tag{2.22}$$
where it was used that $h_{10}=h_{01}$, and they say that reparametrization invariance allows us to choose two of the metric components. Then, only one component will remain and this component, in turn, **can be gauged away by using the invariance of the action under Weyl transformations**. What I understand from the latter claim is that there exist transformations that are taking us from $(\sigma'^0,\sigma'^1)$ to $(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)$, such that
$$h_{\alpha\beta}(\sigma'^1,\sigma'^2)\rightarrow 
h_{\alpha\beta}(\sigma^1,\sigma^2)=e^{-\phi(\tau,\sigma)}
\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0\\ 
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
So that, after the application of the abovementioned transformation, we can perform a transofrmation of the form $h_{\alpha\beta}\rightarrow e^{\phi(\tau,\sigma)}h_{\alpha\beta}$ and reduce the latter metric to the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\alpha\beta}=\text{diag}\{-1,1\}$.

My questions are the following:

1. Why does parametrization invariance allows us to choose two of the components of the metric? Since the action is invariant under parametrizations $\sigma'^{\alpha}\rightarrow\sigma^{\alpha}=f^{\alpha}(\sigma')$, that means we can choose $f^{\alpha}(\sigma')$ to be anything, righta? Hence, since $a=0,1$ we are allowed to choose $f^{0}(\sigma')$ and $f^{1}(\sigma')$, correct? **In other words, does the number of components of the metric that I am allowed to choose equal to the number of dimensions of the world volume?**
2. I am trying to complete an exercise I thought: I would like, given a generic metric $$h_{\alpha\beta}(\sigma'^0,\sigma'^1)=\begin{pmatrix}
     h_{00} & h_{01}\\ 
     h_{01} & h_{11}
   \end{pmatrix}$$
   to deduce which are the most generic transformations to get me to $h_{\alpha\beta}(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)=e^{-\phi(\tau,\sigma)}\text{diag}\{-1,1\}$. The transformation of the metric implies
   $$h_{00}(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)=-e^{-\phi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)}=
   f^2(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)h_{00}+2f(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)\chi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)h_{01}+\chi^2(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)h_{11}\\
   h_{01}(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)=0=
   f(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)g(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)h_{00}+[f(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)\psi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)+g(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)\chi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)]h_{01}+\chi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)\psi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)h_{11}\\
   h_{11}(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)=e^{-\phi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)}=
   g^2(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)h_{00}+2g(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)\psi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)h_{01}+\psi^2(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)h_{11}$$
   where
   $$f(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)=\frac{\partial\sigma'^0}{\partial\sigma^0},\ \ g(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)=\frac{\partial\sigma'^0}{\partial\sigma^1},\ \
   \chi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)=\frac{\partial\sigma'^1}{\partial\sigma^0},\ \
   \psi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)=\frac{\partial\sigma'^1}{\partial\sigma^1}$$
   How to combine the restrictions above in order to find restrictions for the functions $f(\sigma^0,\sigma^1),\ g(\sigma^0,\sigma^1),\ \chi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)$ and $ \psi(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)$?

If the second question is too hard, I could also be satisfied with a specific example of reparametrizations that are not the most generic ones, but would do the job of reducing an arbitrary metric $h_{\alpha\beta}(\sigma'^0,\sigma'^1)$ to the metric $h_{\alpha\beta}(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Diffeomorphism & Weyl transformations in the 2D worldsheet of string theory and the existence of conformal gauge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410900/2451)

Comment: You might find Sec. 2.1.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01055 to be useful